# how to disable features from menu to certain users in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jmenu

I am building inventory management system for my university project. Project is almost completed but i want to give certain access from menu bar to certain users and admin can access all features.
For exampe i want to disable stock menu for sales person and sales menu for stock person.
[image]

Comment: `menuItem.setEnabled(false);` this will do what you need.

Comment: creating profiles (admin vs user vs gues), using conditional statements, or the strategy pattern ....

Comment: can u give sample code for it
Thanks

Comment: The strategy pattern is very popular, there are many articles about it on the internet

Comment: Duplicate of this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246428/disable-menu-items-programatically

Answer (score 1):

Here, In place of String type, you can use your admin type. And set whatever the facilities he has to true. And If you have a feature of logout and login without restarting the app. Then disable the items which are not necessary and dont forget to enable the necessary items.

```
public class JMenuItemExample extends JFrame
{
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -1143292553326545751L;

void initialize()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    jtp.addTab("Panel1", panel);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu mnuFiles = new JMenu("Files");
    mnuFiles.setEnabled(true);

    JMenuItem mnuBuses = new JMenuItem("Buses");
    mnuBuses.setEnabled(true);
    mnuFiles.add(mnuBuses);
    JMenuItem mnuLuxury = new JMenuItem("Luxury Buses");
    mnuLuxury.setEnabled(true);
    mnuFiles.add(mnuLuxury);

    String type = "Luxury";
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Luxury"))
    {
        mnuBuses.setEnabled(false);
        mnuLuxury.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        mnuBuses.setEnabled(true);
        mnuLuxury.setEnabled(false);
    }

    menuBar.add(mnuFiles);
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400, 500);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MenuItem mItem = new MenuItem();
    mItem.initialize();
}
}
```

Comment: Atleast add some documentation/explanation and not just a pure code dump.

Answer (score 0):

Your main code mistake. It may be as below ...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JMenuItemExample mItem = new JMenuItemExample();
    mItem.initialize();
}
```